# Two-armed Shanks after he saves Luffy

Tags: one-piece

As a One Piece fan who doesn't read the manga I must ask this:

In this [flashback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAF4Yq1mIdo) when Ace meets Shanks, Ace says:

> "My brother was always talking about you as his lifesaver"

As you are aware, Shanks lost his arm when he saved Luffy. However, at 0:43 you can clearly see both of his arms.

Does this happen in the manga or is it just an animation mistake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The meeting between Ace and Shanks does happen in the manga, but according to the [One Piece Wiki on Episode 461](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_461) where this happens, Shanks having two arms appears to be an error in the animation.

Personally, I do agree that it was an animation fail, since it was long after Shanks saved Luffy.

Comment: It would be worth noting that in the manga, Shank's cloak covers his left arm entirely. So the error *is* only in the anime.

Comment: @Thebluefish Feel free to add an answer with that piece of information (or if you are generous, edit it in this answer)